# Android ( Intent )

Tags: java, android, android-intent

i have these peace of code taht is written by eclipse and which gives me no syntax error 
but when i run it , it says intent_ has stopped working

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.intent_;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView t1, t2, t3;
    EditText tf1;
    Button b1, b2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome to On create", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        t3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        tf1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                t1.setText("Abed-Almalik");
                t2.setText("Jorda-jerash");
                t3.setText("2010901092");
            }
        });

        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String url = "http://www.google.com";
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Please help me solve the problem 
Thank you !

Comment: your package name `com.example.intent_` should probably be `com.example.intent`. To see the error details please look at the logcat and include it in the question.

Comment: Apart from what @donfuxx says, can you please mention what the problems tab has printed?

Comment: intent_ is my project name so no problem here

Comment: Then please post the logcat output ;-)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `b2` wasn't defined. 

so `b2.setOnClickListener` will give you a null pointer error.

Answer (score 0):

Further to Saba's answer - you have this twice

```
b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

The second one should probably be b2 = ...

Answer (score 0):

You haven't any button b2 for b2.setOnClickListener

//running code is below

```
package com.example.intent_;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView t1, t2, t3;
    EditText tf1;
    Button b1, b2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome to On create", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        t3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);  //here change it to b2 and button2
        tf1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                t1.setText("Abed-Almalik");
                t2.setText("Jorda-jerash");
                t3.setText("2010901092");
            }
        });

        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String url = "http://www.google.com";
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```